# Schrödinger's equation

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Schrodinger's equation has been successfully solved in one-electronic systems, such as the ionic molecular hydrogen $\ce{H2+}$.

What is the exact reason that this equation can not be applied for multielectron atoms?

Comment: It surely can be, and **is** applied. It can't be solved in elementary functions, but that's another story.

Comment: 1) http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39795/why-cannot-the-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-be-solved-exactly-for-systems-in-which-more 2) http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34606/analytical-solution-of-the-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-for-ab-systems 3) http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/how-was-the-quantum-3-body-problem-solved